# vector of struct pointer

Tags: c++, vector

Following is my problem

```
struct point{
     int x;
     int y;
};   

struct OuterStruct 
{
    std ::vector <point *> pa;
    std ::vector <point *> pb;
};

OuterStruct atest; // global variable
```

Now in my main i am doing this

```
point n ;
n.x=1;
n.y =2;
atest.pa.push_back(n);
atest.pb.push_back(n);
```

..

and in some other function if i am using this global stucture ,value of pa,pb is lost,and they has some junk values.
Am i doing something wrong here.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, but based on what you've shown your vectors should be defined as `std::vector<point>`, not `std::vector<point*>`.

Comment: I can't think of a way your code fragments would even form a valid program. Please post a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

Change vector of pointers:

```
struct OuterStruct 
{
    std::vector<point*> pa;
    std::vector<point*> pb;
};
```

into vector of objects:

```
struct OuterStruct 
{
    std::vector<point> pa;
    std::vector<point> pb;
};
```

And also

- use meaningful names (`pa`, `pb`, `atest` and `OuterStruct` don't say much...)
- be consistent in naming convention (if you name types with `UpperCamelCase`, then `point`->`Point`)
- avoid using global variables if possible
- create a custom constructor for `point` to ease its creation:

  ```
  struct point {
      point(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { }
      int x;
      int y;
  };
  ```

  then you can simply do:

  ```
  atest.pa.push_back(point(1,2));
  ```

Comment: With C++11 you could even simplify it to `atest.pa.emplace_back(1, 2);`.